# What academic journals in political science have the highest impact factor?

Tags: political-theory, geopolitics, reference-request, comparative-politics

I am in school for engineering and work as a programmer but I'm almost always reading about politics/philosophy/economics/sociology outside school.
However the sources I get my information from the most are:

1. Well Known Political Theory eg. books like Origins of Totalitarianism Hanah Arendt, Order of Things Foucault, Capital by Marx  etc.
2. Youtube Videos and Podcasts like the Economist, Philosophize This etc.
3. Mainstream Media like Al Jazeera, Foreign Affairs,
4. Bestselling Books like - Jan Werner Muller, Noam Chomsky etc.

But I want to read the same stuff **humanities students read** since my program does not have electives. I want to be in the loop as to what the current papers are, what the latest discussions and research topics are. What journals and review papers can I read and where can I access recent views in political science?

Comment: This seems largely opinion-based and covers a very large range of topics: you want to know what all students of all humanities and social sciences at all levels in all countries read?

Comment: I doubt academics rely on only the news and bestseller books, so I want to know what theyr;e reading. For eg. in engineering school we get snippets of famous engineering journals, which journals should I be looking out for for politics ?

Comment: Have you considered looking in the bibliography of these books and articles that you are reading, that will give you more pointers to what to look for.

Comment: The top journals in the field can be identified with an objective standard (e.g. impact factor). If Ash wishes to reword the question, I think it should be reopened.

Comment: Just re-worded with suggested changes

Comment: I voted (in the review queue) for this question to remain closed, because even though the original close reason no longer applies, this question does not follow the [correct guidance on reference requests, as given on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5846/27084)